# Facebook JS SDK - Post an image to someone's wall and make it open in the Gallery Lightbox

Tags: facebook

To be clear, I know how to post an image to a user's wall using `FB.ui`, but what I would like to know, is if it's possible to make that thumbnail in the post open up the image using the Facebook Gallery Lightbox, just like any pictures you see from your friends, etc. Currently I can only make the thumbnail link to either my app or directly to the image.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you can't do that: the gallery lightbox access is not exposed in any way that you can change in a wall post.